# fs.readFileSync is not a function when importing an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fs

I am developing in vuejs, focused on IPTV service. The problem I am having is that when I want to do the following

```js
const {channels} = require('../lib/utils/index.js');
```

in the file `actions.js` it shows me the following error

```sh
index.js?c45a:26 Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
    at Module.eval (index.js?c45a:26)
    at eval (index.js:64)
    at Module../src/lib/utils/index.js (app.js:958)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:786)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (actions.js?63e0:2)
    at Module../src/store/actions.js (app.js:1005)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:786)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (index.js?4360:1)
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

**../lib/utils/index.js**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const parser = require('iptv-playlist-parser');
const USM3U = require('./urls/us.m3u');


/*** 
 * @async
 * @method GM3U
 * @param {empty}
 * @Summary Generate US m3u file
 * @Description THIS FUNCTION SHOULD NOT BE USED.
 ***/
const GM3U = async() =>{
  const res = await fetch(`${USM3U}`);
  const data = await res.text();
  fs.writeFile('us.m3u' , data , (err) =>{
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }else{
      console.log('The file us.m3u was saved!');
    }
  })
};

const usPlaylist = fs.readFileSync('us.m3u' , {encoding: 'utf8'});
const channels = parser.parse(usPlaylist);


module.exports = {
  channels
};
```

**actions.js**

When I try to make the import I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function`

```js
const {channels} = require('../lib/utils/index.js');
```

Comment: are you using nodejs (express i mean)?

Comment: You can't use `require('fs')` in browser with vuejs

Comment: @iLiA I'm using vuejs for this project!

Comment: @ljubadr Any alternative to solve the issue?

Comment: Move that logic to the backend server and make the ajax request

Answer (score 2):

You can't use fs package with Vue.js framework .Because fs is not frontend technology . Instead of that try to use AJAX call to solve your issue .

Comment: I fixed the problem by moving all the logic to the actions.js file. I know it's not the best way, but at least that way it worked for me.